# Appending text dynamically in a html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html tag in javascript block as follows:

```
 html += '<th><div></div></th><tr style="width:100%">';

 I want to insert var.value in between div , but there is an error


html += '<th><div>"+var.value+"</div></th><tr style="width:100%">';.
```

Whats the correct way of inserting variable.

Comment: Next time, please also state the error message in your question.

Comment: use `+` to concatenate in jquery/javascript like this  `html += '<th><div>' +var.value+ '</div></th><tr style="width:100%">';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace it with

```
html += '<th><div>' + var.value + '</div></th><tr style="width:100%">';.
```

Basically replace double quote `"` with single quote `'`